# Fetching RDF for a topic from Freebase

Tags: rdf, freebase, rdflib

I am trying to replicate the example code in https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/rdf-overview#rdf-documentation to obtain the RDF for a particular topic and store the result in rdflib. After setup, the url is
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/rdf/m/02h40lc?key=XXXXX. 
 However, upon running the code, I get the following error:

```
    "BadSyntax: at line 7 of <>:
     Bad syntax (EOF found in middle of path syntax) at ^ in:
     "@prefix key: <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/>.
      @prefix ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>.
      @prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
      @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
      @prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

      ns:m.02h40lc
          ns:base.database.database_topic.database_s_for_this_topic    ns:m.0861s;
          ns:base.rosetta.languoid.document    ns:m.05tq40j;
          ns:base.rosetta.languoid.document    ns:m.05tqsrm;
```

etc., with the last line being:

```
        rdfs:label    "Inglise keel"@et^..."
```

The actual last line of the file is:

```
    rdfs:label    "Inglise keel"@et.
```

Have I missed some steps in getting the example to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the parser doesn't like embedded periods/dots (.) in the prefixed URIs.

As a workaround, you can expand the ns: & key: prefixed URIs by hand before feeding them to the RDF parser (yes, that kind of defeats the whole point of using a standard parser).  The results should look like this (which I think will parse):

```
  @prefix key: <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/>.
  @prefix ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>.

  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.02h40lc>
      <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/base.database.database_topic.database_s_for_this_topic    <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0861s>;
      <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/base.rosetta.languoid.document    <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05tq40j>;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I was hoping to use Python libraries load the (or a portion of the) RDF dump from Freebase into rdflib for some preliminary processing. It appears as if there is no straightforward way of doing so if I have to handcraft the input files to the parser. I'm curious to know how you and others have approached the problem.

Comment: I don't work with the dumps that much, but when I do, I tend to use zgrep, cut, and other Unix command line tools as opposed to RDF tools.  The transformation that I'm describing would be a couple minutes work with sed, awk, or Python, so shouldn't really be that onerous (although I agree it shouldn't be necessary).